# Longest common prefix of lines

Tags: text-processing, command-line

Given a text file or a stream of text, how can the longest common prefix of two lines be determined and printed to stdout in bash? If there are several longest prefixes, I don't care which one is printed.

For instance, on an input like:

```
abcdef
abc
defgh
abcdeg
defgi
```

The longest common prefix between any two lines is `abcde` (in between the first and fourth), the second longest `defg`, the third `abc`...

Comment: In a stream of text, would you want to do this operation on every pair of adjacent lines, or on all lines?

Comment: bash isn't a text editor

Comment: See [Decomposition of path specs into longest-common-prefix + suffix](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/67121)

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think this is a useful tool to have in one's toolbox because it can be used in a number of scenarios. I thought of this problem because I had several files in a directory and wanted to find out whether two of them were identical. I ran `sha256sum * | sort` and compared the lines manually, but if they were many, that'd be somewhere between cumbersome and impossible. Of course, I could pipe the output to a text file and check whether any two hashes are identical using a different tool, but there probably is a simpler solution.

Comment: @Kusalananda On all lines. But I don't really mind if it only works on adjacent lines because I can simply pipe my stream through `sort` first.

Comment: In your comment above, you say that you are looking whether files are identical or not. This has _nothing_ to do with largest common prefix of individual lines. I am now confused.  If you want to look for identical files, just use `fdupes`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I merely stated the use case I had when I noticed that I don't know how to find the longest common prefix of lines in bash. If I had known how to do that, I would've piped the output of `sha56sum *` to that command (sequence). If the final output was an entire SHA-256 hash, I would've piped the output of `sha256sum *` through `grep` with the hash I found before provided as its only argument. Then the names of the identical files (along with their hashes) would've been printed to the terminal. If the final output was not an entire SHA-256 hash, I would've been done earlier.

Comment: @Kusalananda `fdupes` might be a better solution to the particular problem I had but I want to use generalist tools to be able to solve a wide variety of problems. That's why I didn't at all talk about the last use case I had for this in the question.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like:

```
<file LC_ALL=C sort |
   sed -n 'N;h;s/^\(.*\).*\n\1.*/\1/p;g;D' |
   awk '{l = length}
        l > max {max = l; s = $0}
        END {print s}'
```

We sort the input using byte-to-byte comparison (`sort` in the C locale) which guarantees that lines with the longest common prefix are adjacent.

`sed` finds the longest common prefix between one line and the next by using BRE back-references (`\(.*\).*\n\1` being a captured sequence of characters `\(.*\)` followed by any number of characters `.*`, a newline `\n` and the same sequence of characters as captured earlier `\1`), which we print.

`awk` finds the longest of those (picks the first in the input if there are several, so will be the first in lexical order. Use `>=` instead of `>` to get the last).

Note that it finds the longest common prefix in terms of *characters*. To have it in terms of *bytes*, set `$LC_ALL` to `C` for all 3 commands, not just `sort`. Then for instance, in UTF-8 locales, instead of finding the 2 character `St` as the longest common prefix between `Stéphane` and `Stábat`, it would find the 3 bytes, `St<0xc3>` where `<0xc3>` happens to be the first half of both the `á` and `é` characters.

To have it in terms of *extended grapheme cluster*. For instance so that between `Steps` and `Stéphane` (where `é` is expressed as the two character grapheme cluster `e\u0301`) it finds `St` instead of `Ste`, you could resort to `perl`:

```
<file LC_ALL=C sort |
  perl -Mopen=locale -ne '
    BEGIN{$prev = <>}
    if ("$prev$_" =~ /^(\X*).*\n\1\b{g}/) {
      $l = length($1);
      if ($l > $max) {$max = $l; $s = $1}
    }
    $prev = $_;
    END{print "$s\n"}'
```

(where `\X` matches an *extended grapheme cluster* and `\b{g}` an *extended grapheme cluster boundary* (for which you need perl 5.22.1 or newer)).

If you wanted to find the longest common prefix of *all* the lines in the input (not just any *2* lines in the input), as I initially thought you were asking, that's [answered at that other Q&A here](/a/67121).

Comment: `echo -e "this\nis\na\ntest" | sed -e '1{h;d;}' -e 'G;s,^\(.*\).*\n\1.*,\1,;h;$!d'` should print `t` but prints nothing.

Comment: @UTF-8, those 4 lines don't have a common prefix.

Comment: The common prefix is `t`. Both `this` and `test` start with a `t`.

Comment: @UTF-8, see edit for what I believe should now answer your question.